# Is this question suitable for MO?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently posted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470904/lie-algebra-of-a-normalizer) question on MO. However, it quickly got downvoted and there was a comment which read that "MO is not for homework."

However, that question was not homework and I had not got any response on Math.SE and so I put it here. I am trying to self-study and learn things on my own.

---

Is it a bad practice to put questions here if you need clarification and are not able to find on Math.SE?

Comment: No, this question does not appear to be appropriate.

Comment: MathOverflow is for research mathematicians; merely being 'self-study' does not make it appropriate.

Comment: If it is an exercise in a textbook, it is unlikely to be on topic for MO (there are probably textbooks that are exceptions to this). If you ask on MSE and don't get an answer, consider putting a bounty on the question. Often, people will use the term homework for any problem that seems to be from a textbook, regardless of whether the asker has been set it as homework. The reason for this is that the type of answer that will help the asker the most will often be the same.

Comment: Thanks for all your views.